# Ansible/Jinja: how to convert number to binary format

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to generate a random 128-bit number and get it's binary representation, b64-encoded.

Sample:

```
vagrant@ubuntu1804:~$ consul keygen
TUlzi8BWwPQR1zyjR1TiAQ==
```

in it's b64 decoded form:

```
vagrant@ubuntu1804:~$ consul keygen | base64 -d|hexdump -C
00000000  46 b8 72 4b ce 9a 2a 14  09 7b 16 51 99 1b 39 e0  |F�rK�.*..{.Q..9�|
00000010
```

I can generate the large number with `random` filter:

```
{{ 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 | random }}
```

I know I can encode it with `b64encode`, but have no idea how to convert the number to the binary format.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of converting (which is impossible as you can't store/process binary using native Ansible data structures), write a simple filter plugin (`filter_plugins/myfilters.py`) which would generate the content you want:

```
import os
import base64


class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'binary_random_b64_encoded': self.binary_random_b64_encoded
        }

    def binary_random_b64_encoded(self, size):
        return base64.b64encode(os.urandom(size)).decode('ascii')
```

and use it (with the requested size of the binary data):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ 16 | binary_random_b64_encoded }}"
```

Comment: this returns `b'O6hpZnFPlYjganye778Ydg=='`, any idea how to retype that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `{{ 16 | binary_random_b64_encoded | type_debug }}` → `"msg": "str"`

Comment: adding `.decode('ascii')` to `base64.b64encode` did the job.

Comment: Oh, there's a difference between Python 2 and 3... updated.